# How to retain data for dynamically created controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I have the following situation:

- I have 2 drop down lists (DDL) with auto-postback enabled.
- When the user selects something from first DDL, he can choose stuff from 2nd DDL.
- When the user selects something from 2nd DDL, I open database (WHERE clause of SQL query is filled with values from DDLs), and dynamically create several text boxes, labels and buttons which I place inside a placeholder.

The problem is: when I click on some of the dynamically created buttons, nothing happens, and I can't retrieve data from dynamically created boxes. Also, placeholder content is lost (all controls).

So my question is: how do I retain data from dynamically created controls on postback?

I have listed a lot of similar articles on this site, and none solves my problem. Another thing is - I can't use view state nor session.

Code is:

```
public Button btn1 = new Button();
public TextBox txtBoxC1 = new TextBox();
public TextBox txtBoxC2 = new TextBox();
public TextBox txtBoxC3 = new TextBox();
...
...
...
protected void ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
 ...
 if some conditions are met:
 ...
 ...
 String CS4 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStringName"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection conn4 = new SqlConnection(CS4))
 {
  SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("Select * from table where column1=" + 
  Convert.ToInt32(ddl2.SelectedValue)+" order by column1", conn4);
  conn4.Open();
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    txtBoxC1.Text = rdr["column1"].ToString(); txtBoxC1.MaxLength = 3; txtBoxC1.Columns = 3; txtBoxC1.ID = ddl2.SelectedValue + "1";
    txtBoxC2.Text = rdr["column2"].ToString(); txtBoxC2.MaxLength = 3; txtBoxC2.Columns = 3; txtBoxC2.ID = ddl2.SelectedValue + "2";
    txtBoxC3.Text = rdr["column3"].ToString(); txtBoxC3.MaxLength = 3; txtBoxC3.Columns = 3; txtBoxC3.ID = ddl2.SelectedValue + "3";
    btn1.Text = "click me"; btn1.ID = ddl1.SelectedValue; btn1.Click += btn1_Click;
    phDynamic.Controls.Add(btn1);
    phDynamic.Controls.Add(txtBoxC1);
    phDynamic.Controls.Add(txtBoxC2);
    phDynamic.Controls.Add(txtBoxC3);
  }
 }
}
...
...
...
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Write(txtBoxC1.Text+txtBoxC2.Text+txtBoxC3.Text);
}
```

So instead of getting back values from my 3 textboxes, I don't get back anything, and I also lose placeholder controls.

Comment: Create `DataTable` on the fly...Add one row... save `DataTable` in `Session` and continue.....

Comment: Why can't you use view state or session?

Comment: Because it's disabled in my environment. So no sessions and no view states.

Comment: Then I think you would have to store your state in a temporary table in your SQL Server database.  How does this sound to you?

Comment: Perhaps you should re-evaluate your design. When a user does something as simple as changing the values in a dropdownlist, do you really want the entire form to post to the server, and for the server to have to regenerate a response? That's a lot of overhead. It's bad for resources and slow for users. Instead, why don't you use some [JavaScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on the client side to make [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests to a [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)? Much less overhead and easier to create a positive user experience.

Comment: Then reinvent viewstate. Who can stop you from creating hidden fields and serializing/deserializing state to it?

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that the controls have the absolute exact same name each and every time. You will also need to re-create them again in the OnLoad event at the lastest on the next postback (with the exact same IDs) otherwise they don't exist to match up any form data.

Comment: Thank you all for help. I still have this problem unsolved. I have tried several of your suggestions.  Even if I turn on view state, I still don't get back anything (I set up view state in btn1_Click event; on page load when I try to Response.Write(ViewState["Key"]) I don't get anything).

edit: I'm generating buttons/textboxes before anything else (inside public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl, and before OnInit or Page_Load events). Then in PageLoad I add up IDs. Still can't get data out of the controls.

Any help greatly appreciated.